# ODBC connection: "The connection has been disabled"

Tags: vb.net, odbc

I have a 32bit ODBC connector called `IPEOPLE` I'm trying to connect with using VB. If I open Access and use the ODBC drive `IPEOPLE`, it works okay and I'm able to see the data under the same user.

In VB, I'm getting this kind of error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   System.Transactions Critical: 0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled exceptionNMIALERTS.vshost.exeSystem.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089The connection has been disabled.   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.ConnectionIsAlive(Exception innerException)
>      at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleErrorNoThrow(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)

Below that error:

> ERROR [42000] [IPeople][Meditech ODBC Driver (5.0.0.36)][IPD 3.41] No fields in select
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

When I run the SQL in Access, it works just fine. The query is fine. There is very clearly a field being selected (`LIVE.NMISAA.QueueMessages.MessageID`).

And I'm not really sure why. It's not disabled. It can be used just fine via Access. There is no "disabled" indicator on Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator. "NMIALERTS2" is a User DSN on my machine.

The code:

```
    Dim myConnection As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection()
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "DSN=NMIALERTS2"

    Dim strQueryErxE1 As String = "SELECT LIVE.NMISAA.QueueMessages.MessageID FROM LIVE.NMISAA.QueueMessages " & _
        "WHERE LIVE.NMISAA.QueueMessages.QueueConnection = 'ERX_E_XO' and LIVE.NMISAA.QueueMessages.MessageID > '" & strPrevMsgID_ERX_E_XO & "'"

        Dim command1 As OdbcCommand
        Dim command2 As OdbcCommand

        If Active_ERX_E_XO = True Then
            command1 = New OdbcCommand(strQueryErxE1, connection) 'errors here
            command2 = New OdbcCommand(strQueryErxE2, connection)
        End If
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I've rebuilt the code from scratch from 4000 lines to a minimal 30 lines to test the ODBC only, and the exact same issue is occurring. Here is my entire code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim myConnection As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection = New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection()
        myConnection.ConnectionString = "DSN=NMIALERTS2"

        Dim strQueryErxE1 As String = "SELECT LIVE.NMISAA.QueueMessages.MessageID FROM LIVE.NMISAA.QueueMessages " & _
    "WHERE LIVE.NMISAA.QueueMessages.QueueConnection = 'ERX_E_XO' and LIVE.NMISAA.QueueMessages.MessageID > '3000'"

        Dim command1 As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand
        Dim strIIRADT1 As String = ""

        Using connection As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(myConnection.ConnectionString)

            command1 = New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand(strQueryErxE1, connection) 'error here

            connection.Open()

            Dim reader1 As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader

            reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader()

            If reader1.HasRows Then
                While reader1.Read
                    strIIRADT1 = reader1(0).ToString
                End While
            End If

        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You must document the inner exception.  A first-chance exception notification does not necessarily indicate a problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I added it to my question. It makes me more confused, but the query is just fine (works in Access)

Comment: @LarsTech Nope. Literally all the data elements in IPEOPLE are Text. I don't ask why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging back into the 136 line error, I found this buried:

> Database 'xyz' was not found in catalog 'LIVE' or your user does not have rights to the database or the database was not included in the DSN

So basically I had configured the ODBC wrong. The VB was okay. This solved the issue after changing the ODBC type in this custom driver.

Comment: How did you "change the odbc type to the custom driver"?